# Add filtering my questions to show only uncheckmarked questions

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, stack-overflow

I'm an active user of SO, both for questions and answers. I take the time to write plenty of answers, but I also am still quite green, so I ask quite a few questions as well.

Every so often, I will forget to return to checkmark one of my questions, usually because I find most of the responses I receive inadequate. However, after some time I'll usually go back and checkmark at least the best answer of the question.

It would be nice to show me a view of only my unanswered questions, so that I don't have to scroll through 7 pages of questions to check for ones I missed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could just bookmark a search for [your questions without accepted answers](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=user:82320+hasaccepted:0) (user:me+hasaccepted:0).

Comment: Excellent -- does exactly what I need. Thanks!